# Automated test with Appium Selenium iOS

Tags: java, ios, selenium, junit, appium

I develop automated test with iPhone, Selenium and Appium. I need to perform touch action on current screen position.

Can You help me? Do You have any sample code? I checked this solution but it doesn't work

```
new TouchActions(wd).down(0, 0).move(150, 0).perform();
```

Comment: what you want to perform? want to scroll to down or something else?

Comment: I would like to perform tap

Answer (score 0):

try to use TouchAction class this way:

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction();
action.longPress(webElement).moveTo(webElement).release().perform();
```

Comment: how to create another action? When I create another action I got error message. An error occurred while executing user supplied JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(appiumDriver);
    System.out.println(startx+" "+starty);
    System.out.println("Entering swipe");

        System.out.println("Swipe from "+startx +" " +starty +"to" +endx +" " +endy );
        touchAction.press(startx, starty).waitAction(duration).moveTo(endx,endy).release().perform();
```